# Create 3d surface plot using persp in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I want to generate a 3d surface plot using “persp”.
I have 25 x and y coordinates:

```
x<-c(-3.5,-2.5,-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,-3.5,-2.5,-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5)
y<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)
```

and accordingly 25 z coordinates:

```
z<-c(7.25E-08,1.20E-07,1.26E-07,1.26E-07,1.58E-07,6.93E-08,1.29E-07,9.57E-08,7.59E-08,1.59E-08,8.75E-08,1.37E-07,2.08E-07,1.41E-07,1.40E-07,9.46E-08,6.90E-08,7.41E-08,8.84E-08,1.21E-07,2.09E-07,1.80E-07,1.19E-07,9.31E-08,7.79E-08)
```

I want to have a plot where every z-value is set at it´s location (x,y). As I learned

```
persp(x,y,z)
```

does not work. Which is the easiest way?

Comment: z needs to be a 25x25 matrix, ie you need 625 values for z.

Comment: What is the x by y matrix? 17 x 3 (unique values for x and y, respectively)? Try to match your data to the structure used in the examples in `?persp`.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean I have to build a matrix that contains my coordinates x,y,z but also all other x,y coordinates for which no z exists? Probably I then had to fill the non-existent z values with "NA". I already thought about that but was hoping that there is an easier way.

Comment: It is data from the multifocal electroretinogram. The problem is that values are ordered in a hexagon structure and not in a rectangular structure. I try to upload the scheme as a .bmp so it is easer to understand

Comment: It is easily possible to address x,y and z coordinates using ?scatterplot3d. The problem with this function is that connecting the datapoints to a surface plot is difficult and that´s why I tried ?persp. Cannot upload image here sorry.

Comment: @Roman: trying to match the data to the function is NOT a good approach. And sometimes you just can't. Rather adapt the function to the data you have. This is the reason why R have many (more or less) marvellous package ;)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I mean to say to match the structure of user's data to the structure used to create examples.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `persp` documentation, you need increasing values for `x` and `y`.
This is not possible with your data.

When you need to draw some discrete surface from `3` vector of equal lengths, you should rather go for `rgl`:

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Thanks. plot3d works but only generates a 3d scatterplot as does scatterplot3d. Is there an easy way to use plot3d and connect the different data points to form a surface?